# How to nail LVL beam to King Stud

Tags: framing

This seems to be the best forum to get answers. I asked a question a week ago about placement of LVL beam, it was answered in a matter of minutes.

So I am placing this 13ft (12.8ft) Versa-Lam LVL beam as header for a 12ft patio door. You can see the opening I have. I will be adding 3-1/2 by 3-1/2 Versa-Lam LVL posts as Jack studs on each side against the King studs that already exist there once I build up the support wall.

Right now, the king stud that exists on the left side is right at a corner wall. It the very last King stud right at the corner. And I have no access to the opposite side of the King Stud for nailing the beam to it.

Once I place the beam, how do I nail it to the king stud? Do I just toe nail it?

I appreciate any comment. Thanks

[image: LVL Header]

Answer (score 1):

Toe nailing should provide sufficient strength. A method I often apply in such situations is to not only nail it both through the header and into the king stud but to also toe nail it from the king stud into the header. You can also put some nails up through the jacks and into the header. If you lack confidence in your nails, a few well placed screws should do the trick as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Would it pass inspection? I guess what i mean is, would there be a certain number of nails required for inspection purposes? Thanks

Comment: Do you have inspection where you live? This is something that you can always improve on later. If you put in a reasonable amount of nails it shouldn't be a problem. One thing you could always add is a thin metal strap from Simpson's. It reaches from the top plate down across the header and onto the jacks and gets fastened with nails.

Comment: Yes, inspection will be done after framing it.

Comment: I am speaking from experience and so far there was never any problem in such a situation concerning the structural integrity or the inspection. However, maybe there is someone on here who knows what the building codes say  about nailing headers into king studs.

Comment: Thanks Bluejay, it seems sufficient to me as well; i’ll see if others comment on code requirements.

Comment: Hi again alemiss... Sorry your not getting your answer. You might want to read through this page. https://www.contractortalk.com/f14/how-many-nails-through-king-stud-into-side-header-26053/#/topics/26053?page=1

Comment: Thanks BlueJay, that was helpful actually. I think I will call the inspector tomorrow and ask him directly. Heck he should know. It's my own house anyways. Thanks

Comment: Great! Please let us know what he says.

Answer (score 0):

The 2017 ICC Residential Code calls for 5-8d box, or 4-8d common, or 4-10d box nails for fastening header to stud. (Toe nail application.) See Table R602.3(1) Fastening Schedule, Item #11.

BTW, generally we don’t worry about this nailing pattern because the exterior sheathing will have many more than 4 or 5 nails in both the header and stud that secures the two together with nailing in shear, rather than toenailed. However, in your case, I doubt if you’ll go back and renail the sheathing.

Comment: Thanks Lee, I appreciate the input. What are your thoughts on using Fasten Masters flat lock instead of nails? https://www.fastenmaster.com/product-details/flatlok-structural-wood-screw.html

Comment: The Code does not “directly” approve them as a substitute, but the manufacturer may have an approval. I’d check their website. I prefer a metal clip in a situation like yours (not secured with exterior wall sheathing) like Simpson A-35 clip.

Comment: Thank you Lee, Bluejay mentioned the Simpson clip as well. Great help here. Thank you all.