# Header beam nailing code requirement

Tags: framing

I asked a version of [this question yesterday](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157805/how-to-nail-lvl-beam-to-king-stud), but now I would like to know exactly what the code says when it comes to nailing.

So I am placing this 13ft (12.8ft) Versa-Lam LVL beam as header for a 12ft patio door. You can see the opening I have. I will be adding 3-1/2 by 3-1/2 Versa-Lam LVL posts as Jack studs on each side against the King studs that already exist there once I build up the support wall.

Right now, the king stud that exists on the left side is right at a corner wall. It the very last King stud right at the corner. And I have no access to the opposite side of the King Stud for nailing the beam to it.

Once I place the beam, what are the code requirements for nailing it to the king stud? Do I just toe nail it?

[image: LVL Beam Framing]

Comment: I think this is going to get closed as a duplicate.  I have tried to rescue it by suggesting an edit that makes it clear that *this* question is asking about the specifics of code requirements (rather than the practicalities).  I suggest you approve the edit, or make a similar one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I kind of thought it would be problematic as well. Thanks again